# Child component gets rendered twice onGroupClick event

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am a beginner in android and I trying to make use of `ExpandableListView` and was having a some issues.

I have a `setOnGroupClickListner` event in my Activity for the `ExpandableListView`. For some reason when I click the group, it renders the `childView twice`, and in order to close it, I have to click twice. On each click only one of the `childView` gets hidden.

The following was my code

```
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_list);

    alist = new Alist(this, headings, childItems);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(alist);

    //setting an expand group listener
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            Log.e("onGroupClick:", "worked");
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now I somehow could resolve this issue if instead of `return false` , I write `return true` in the `onGroupClick` function.

Can someone explain me what effect does it have to resolve the issue? I read somewhere that if I `return true`, it means that the `click was handled`, but I an not able understand what it exactly means.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `ExpandableListView`, but to me it looks like you don't have to `setOnGroupClickListener` explicitly, because it's automatically done for you. If you still need to change the default behavior, then you're free to override it, but you need to return true to signalize that the event is consumed and the default event will not be fired.

Comment: Yeah it's true that the setOnGroupClickListener is not mandatory. It's works without it too.